# Java json object call function by name

Tags: java, jquery, json

I'm wondering if it is possible to call a function from a java json object?

Example

java:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("fnRowCallback", "test()");
```

jquery:

```
$ (function () {
    "use strict";
    function test() {
        alert('test');
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Ultimate accomplishment needed.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("fnRowCallback", function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
                if (aData["rush"] == "Rush" ) {
                    $(nRow).addClass("gradeX");  
                }
            });
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What is your underlying goal?

Comment: Your JSON code is on the server. You're trying to call a jQuery function `test()` on the client. How is it likely to achieve?

Comment: I'm a tapestry5 user and I'm trying to use jquery datatable. The component is initialized with a java json object. The problem I'm facing is trying to add this configuration, json.put("fnRowCallback", "function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {alert('test'); "); However json objects do not accept functions, so I was hoping to be able to call the function.

Comment: @Lion, tapestry5 outputs the json object to the client

Comment: Evaluating random strings as Javascript code is probably a bad idea. How much you can trust the source?

Comment: Can you, instead of transmitting a function, transmit its name (from a predefined set) instead?

Comment: JSON response cannot simulate a jQuery/JavaScript function call - as per my knowledge.

Comment: @JanDvorak, I'm not sure I follow you?

Comment: @Lion assuming the receiving side doesn't cooperate. If it does, however...

Comment: @George nor am I sure I understand what you want

Comment: JSON cannot force anything to happen. JSON is just a string - what happens is defined by the receiver - and a receiver shouldn't execute untrusted arbitrary code.

Comment: @JanDvorak, I updated my question with my ultimate goal. I'm just not sure how to pass this configuration into the json object which gets passed into the client by tapestry and read by the datatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up answering my own question. The solution is to use a JSONLiteral like so,

Java

```
public JSONObject getOptions() {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("fnRowCallback", new JSONLiteral(String.format("fnRowCallback()")));
    return json;
}
```

JS.

```
function fnRowCallback(){
    var fnRowCallback = function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
        if (aData["rush"] == "Rush" ) {
            nRow.className = nRow.className + " gradeX";  
        }
    };
    return fnRowCallback;
}
```

Thanks Everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this if you instead have your Java return javascript.

```
<script src="myjavapage.jsp"></script>
```

have your Java return

```
$(function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

however I can't think of a good reason to code it this way rather than instead having a js file that gets the content on demand using ajax and not including code in your json. It seems pretty pointless.

Comment: Perhaps I'm going about this all the wrong way. I'm working from the following example, http://tapestry5-jquery.com/docs/components/docsdatatables tab 2 line 60. I'm trying to incorporate this example, http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks "fnRowCallback"

Comment: What does that("fnRowCallback") have to do with a json object?

Comment: fnRowCallback would be my key in my json object. If you looked at the first link I posted, you'll notice the component is configured on the serverside with a json object, but in the example on datatables, they configure it directly in javascript which doesn't appear to be an option for me. My pair would be the function, I'm not sure how to pass that function in as a pair as json objects are nothing other than strings.

Comment: How are you going to get it from the json string to the `dataTable` plugin?

Comment: The actually tapestry component passes the json object into the datatable as an argument, but the problem is the function is being passed in as a string rather than an executable function. I thought maybe I could just pass a function name into the json object and use it to call the function. I honestly don't know how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

See [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
var obj = {
   foo: function() {
    console.log('foo called');
   }
};

var json = {method: "foo"};

obj[json.method].call(this);
```